# Avahi daemon uses excessive amounts of CPU?

Tags: cpu, cpu-load, avahi, htop

It seems that `avahi-daemon` process, which is unknown to me, is using excessive amounts of CPU on my system

I have tried both `htop` and system monitor, and only `htop` show the CPU use. Screenshots are included below.

What can I do to make `avahi-daemon` behave?

Edit: The issue often occurs when playing the game Dota 2. I've been observing this for a week.

[image: htop]

[image: System Monitor]
System monitor doesn't appear to show which process is consuming CPU, unlike htop.

[image: sudo systemctl status avahi-daemon.s*]
As requested by @heynnema

Comment: It turned out that 1 processor core is always maxed out for no reason, with all programs closed. To be honest I don't really know what the user avahi` is. But if it is true that `avahi` consumes 99% of CPU time, all 4 cores must be at full load. 1 out of 4 should be 25% (at least in the case of Windows Task Manager).

Comment: Even if there is a single looping thread, the OS should be able to "split" the workload to all 4 cores (by running it on each core for a short period of time), resulting in 25% CPU utilization on each core. I really don't know why it is locked to a single CPU core like that.

Comment: Edit your question with the output of `sudo systemctl status avahi-daemon.s*`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @heynnema I did what you requested. Please take a look, thanks. The command was run while `avahi` was using 100% CPU time of 1 core. If I reboot, everything is back to normal. It often occurs when I play the game Dota 2 for a while.

Comment: @vidarlo I have limited knowledge about how the OS schedules threads for the CPU to process. But from what I have been observing for many years, single threaded programs are not locked to  a single CPU core. Let's say you open 7-Zip and choose compression mode with 1 thread, you'll see the workload is split across all CPU cores in Windows Task Manager. Or maybe I am missing something here?

Comment: They are not locked to a single core, and can be moved. But moving incurs a penalty, as it takes time. You cannot split a single thread across multiple cores, but then again 7-zip is multithreaded. So yes, you are missing something.

Comment: Please do not post text as pictures. Copy from the terminal, and paste into the question. Please see https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code on how to format command output.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Dota 2, but you might check it's prefs, looking for something having to do with network, or devices, or scanning. They've recently released an update on March 11 that you might check out. http://www.dota2.com/news/updates/

Comment: @vidarlo By "splitting", I mean running a single thread on each CPU core for a short amount of time, resulting in "balanced" CPU utilization in Windows Task Manager, ie: 25% on 4 cores instead of 100% on 1 core. Thanks to your information, now that I know it leads to some performance penalties. Anyway, Windows always moves the thread to all CPU cores, and it seems it is its default behavior. You are welcome to try any programs you want. As long as they are single-threaded, and you have more than 1 CPU core, you won't see any of them running at 100%.

Comment: No, windows will not move running threads if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 7):

Avahi daemon basically a network daemon that broadcasts your machine's IP address to the network. For example A printer broadcast its IP using Avahi daemon saying that "I am a printer and I can print your documents" if you don't have any such devices to be used in the network, you can disable the daemon using the below commands on Ubuntu

```
sudo systemctl disable avahi-daemon
```

Sometimes other software starts this daemon, so you can remove them permanently using the below commands.

```
apt-get remove avahi-daemon
```

Comment: At my office (university), there are a lot of printers, apparently linked to MacBookAir, probably shared by default instead of stay private, and even if I removed it, there are come back (under Jammy-22.04). I run `sudo kill -9 <avahi-daemon pid>`, and it ma fans stops to running.

Comment: That leads to new problems. To avoid error messages in systemd, you have to disbble the avahi socket too: `sudo systemctl disable avahi-daemon.socket`

Comment: But now the the dbus-daemon complains every few seconds that cups-browsed needs avahi.

Comment: @Erich so disable cups-browsed as well `sudo systemctl disable cups-browsed.service`. This is just another part of the printer-finding system.

Answer (score 3):

Avahi is required for multiple things regarding network and/or plug and play devices.
Disabling it may disable some of services that you might need, depending on your computer use.

It was also consuming my cpu because I am part of large network, with lot's of printers.

What eventually did it for me, without disrupting print functionality is:

```
sudo nano /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf
```

find `ratelimit-interval-usec=` and set it to **500000**
find `ratelimit-burst=` and set that to **500**
find `enable-wide-area=` and set that to **no**

press ctrl + o then save

restart avahi daemon

```
sudo systemctl restart avahi-daemon.service
```

Check CPU usage...

If above doesn't quickly resolve high CPU usage, further limitations
can be done in rlimits section of avahi's config file, see man page or:

https://manpages.debian.org/testing/avahi-daemon/avahi-daemon.conf.5.en.html

For detailed instructions.

See this answer for more details about Avahi: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/566932/what-is-the-avahi-daemon